# ¿Cómo saber el día de la semana de una fecha? - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

Estoy necesitando saber el día de la semana de una fecha dada. Tengo mi variable @fecha que contiene lo siguiente al mostrarla:

> 2020-02-03

Lo que necesito es de esa fecha saber el día de la semana, ejemplo si '03.02.2020' es lunes me devuelva un '1'

He probado de la siguiente manera y no me funcionó:

```
$fecha.strftime("%u")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu fecha debe ser un objeto `Date` (o `DateTime`) para poder utilizar el método `strftime`; no puedes utilizarlo directamente en un *String*.

Utiliza el método `Date.parse` para convertir tu *String* a `Date`, e.g.:

```
Date.parse("2020-02-03").strftime("%u")
#=> "1"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Me ha funcionado muy bien !! Siempre atento